# How to change text in Root.master on an event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, master-pages

I have a project in VS 2013 with master page. In the Root.master I have the "Log In" which redirects me to the login page.

```
<a href="Logare.aspx" runat="server" id="loginLink">Log In</a>
```

When I login I'm redirected to a certain page, let's say it Default.aspx.

In Default.aspx.cs I have:

```
if (Session["username"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Logare.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                loginLink.Text ="Welcome, "+ Session["username"];
            }
```

How could I do so when I'm logged in the text from  Root.master to change from "Log In" to "Welcome, username"? I tried to get the loginLink id from Root.master but it's not known in Default.aspx.cs.

**UPDATE**

This is how "Log In" from Root.master is now:

```
<a href="Logare.aspx"><asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Log In"></asp:Label></a>
```

In Default.aspx.cs I have now:

```
if (Session["username"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Logare.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Label mpLabel = new Label();
                mpLabel = (Label)Master.FindControl("Label8");                                   mpLabel.Text = "Welcome, " + Session["username"];
            }
```

But, with this, I'm getting an error

> > Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

at  `mpLabel.Text = "Welcome, " + Session["username"];`

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. If `loginLink` id defined in the master aspx, then it is available in master's code behind, but not on the page. So you should have not issues accessing it by ID in the code behind of the master and running exactly same code you posted here.

Comment: Defaul.aspx is in the main content. The login is in Root.master. So is there a way to reference that as a sort of global variable which to may be seen on Default.aspx?

Comment: I still do not understand your use case, but if accessing master page controls from the page is what you want, you can always use `Master.FindControl()`. Another option is to expose controls on the master via public properties, and then call them on the page

Comment: I tried insted of `loginLink.Text ="Welcome, "+ Session["username"];`,
`Label mpLabel = (Label) Master.FindControl("loginLink");
                mpLabel.Text="Welcome, "+ Session["username"];`, but it gives me this error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: How could I expose controls on the master via public properties?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood your question correctly, this is just about accessing control declared on the master page from within the content page code behind. You have two options to achieve that.

1. FindControl

Code is simple (borrowed from OP's own comment):

```
Label mpLabel = (Label) Master.FindControl("loginLink");
```

However be aware that `FindControl` works only with immediate children of the control. So if your structure looks like

```
MasterPage
    Control1
        Control2
            loginLink
```

You will need to something like this:

```
Control c1 = Master.FindControl("Control1");
Control c2 = c1.FindControl("Control2");
Label mpLabel = (Label) c2.FindControl("loginLink");
```

Alternatively you can use recursive version of `FindControl` . It is not available out of the box, but many (really many) versions are on the web already. Here is [one](http://blog.codinghorror.com/recursive-pagefindcontrol/).

2. Expose controls via Master's interface

In your master page code behind define a property like that:

```
public Label LoginLabel
{
    get { return this.loginLabel; }
}
```

And on the content page just use it. Don't forget to cast master to your specific type:

```
Label loginLabel = ((YourMasterPageClass)Master).LoginLabel;
```

That might not be particularly safe, so you can expose just label text instead:

```
public Label LoginLabelText
{
    get { return this.loginLabel.Text; }
    set { this.loginLabel.Text = value; }
}


((YourMasterPageClass)Master).LoginLabelText = "Welcome!";
```

Comment: I updated with information my question. When you say "YourMasterPageClass" you mean my Root.master page?

Comment: Please make sure to re-visit the part of the answer that talks about FindControl, I am pretty sure it is not working for you because of the nested controls. And `YourMasterPageClass` stands, well, for the class of the master page. Take a look at the code behind of the master, you'll see it is actually a class declared there. That's the one I mean

Comment: The only thing I have there is:
`public partial class RootMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            ASPxSplitter1.GetPaneByName("Header").Size = ASPxWebControl.GlobalTheme == "Moderno" ? 95 : 83;
           
 ASPxSplitter1.GetPaneByName("Header").MinSize = ASPxWebControl.GlobalTheme == "Moderno" ? 95 : 83;
        }
    }`
I'm sorry but just started to work with master pages so that's why I'm confused and don't know how to do it. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: RootMaster is your class then. The rest you need to write yourself

Comment: Let me see if I got it right. In Root.master.cs I must put `public Label LoginLabel
{
    get { return this.loginLabel; }
}`, right? If yes, something's wrong because it doesn't recognize  who `loginLabel` is.

Comment: That was a typo. Please do not take this all literally and just copy-paste. It's your code after all, you need to understand what is going on, right. Try to grasp the idea instead. Idea here is that this should a control which you want to access in th content page

Comment: I was just trying to adapt for my code what you suggested in the second option of your solution.